# Bluetooth Connection In Raspberry PI

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux

I want to create a python script so that when user wants pair with Raspberry PI's Bluetooth by phone I accept the request by pressing on a button connected to Raspberry PI's GPIO. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look at `gpio_keys` for the button service from kernel side and handle it in user space as you want.

Comment: Can you give my more detail

Comment: What's the reason for willing to do this? You can use bluetoothctl agent's which accept every pair without even bothering to use a external button.